# Pinky in traditional grip flying out for no reason

Tags: drums

So I'm a new marching snare player and I've been practicing traditional grip for about 3 months now, and my technique has improved a ton over these months. But as of yesterday, my pinky in my left hand just decides to fly out from under my ring finger and no matter what I do I can't stop it. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Some players will link the third and fourth fingers together with an elastic band until the fingers behave themselves. And when practicing, focus all your attention on that problem finger.